Tempos verbais do inglês para o português
Olá, estou estudando inglês diariamente e tenho enfrentado algumas dificuldades com os tempos verbais desse idioma. Há vários tempos que expressam ações passadas, presentes e futuras, mas estou confuso sobre como isso se traduz para o português.
Então eu gostaria de saber qual seria a "equivalência" de todos os tempos verbais do inglês para o português. Isso me ajudaria a ter uma compreensão melhor em textos, conversas, vídeos etc.
Aliás, eu tenho um nível razoável na língua inglesa ainda, por isso peço perdão caso tenha dito algo estranho. Sempre tento melhorar meu inglês a cada dia.
Se alguém puder me ajudar a esclarecer essa questão, ficarei muito agradecido!
Obrigado!

Mesmo se fizéssemos uma lista, os tempos verbais em inglês não têm equivalentes diretos em português em geral, o uso é diferente. Por exemplo, o "preterite" seria traduzido para o pretérito perfeito ou para o pretérito imperfeito, dependendo do contexto. Recomendo estudar cada tempo verbal do inglês de cada vez.

Você precisa dar exemplos. Senão ver um livro de gramática.

Não há uma equivalência direta entre os tempos verbais do português e do inglês, como o Schilive já comentou e El-Dash e Busnardo explicam (também aqui):

[...] a semântica verbal subjacente nas duas línguas é bastante diferente.
[...] Formas semanticamente obrigatórias em uma língua que não têm contrapartida na outra — como seria o caso do aspecto verbal do present perfect do inglês e do imperfeito do português — são exemplos [das diferenças].
[...] frequentemente existe uma uma falta de equivalência, quer devido a lacunas semânticas, quer a hábitos sintáticos diferentes.

O texto também enfatiza a óbvia importância do contexto e inclusive discorre um tanto sobre as dificuldades resultantes para os estudantes de inglês.
Contudo, naturalmente existem correspondências que surgem com maior frequência e um trabalho de Maria Terra, que se dedicou a estudar essa estatística se baseando num corpus bilíngue, produziu a seguinte tabela, que provavelmente é a melhor aproximação do que se pede na pergunta:



Tempos Verbais no português
Principais traduções para o inglês
Frequência




Presente do Indicativo
Simple Present
79%


Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo
Simple Past
83%


Pretérito Imperfeito do Indicativo
Simple Past
95%


Futuro do Indicativo
Future Simple
60%


Presente do Subjuntivo
Simple Present (that-clause)
44%



Mas, se me permite o conselho: quando o objetivo é aprimorar uma língua, concentrar-se em tradução não é a melhor abordagem. Há recursos como cursos, vídeos ou livros online gratuitos (por exemplo este e este) com explicações, exemplos e exercícios que não se baseiam em tradução e que podem dar um impulso muito maior na aquisição da língua do que se preocupar com como os tempos seriam traduzidos para o português.
